# Good microservice pattern for "object based" sql database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, microservices

We have a legacy application based on SQL server and win32 middle-tier. Now, I’m searching for good solutions to write a microservice based REST based API to provide access to the data. We like to use VS, C# or JS and azure.
A specialty of this application is, the Database has an uncommon "object based" approach. Each entity, say persons, files, groups, articles have a relation to a common “object” table. In this table common attributes are stored. There are also common 1-n related tables like categories. Each “object” has a unique guid.

```
person      -->
file        -->   object   ---> objectcategories
article     -->
```

The new api should provide methods like:

```
GET /person/1 ->
{
    lastname: "Doe", prename: "John", sex: "m",
    guid: "{guid}", owner: "123",  // object specific attributes
}

GET /file/1 -> 
{
    filename:"test.docx", size:"123",
    guid: "{guid}", owner: "123",  // object specific attributes
}

GET /object/{guid-a} -->
{
    // Returns either file or Person data
}
```

It should also allow to load additional data like

```
GET /person/1?categories ->
{
    lastname: "Doe", prename: "John", sex: "m",
    guid: "{guid}", owner: "123",  // object specific Attributes
    categories: [
         "green", "blue"
    }
}
```

In reverse, it would be cool to simply safe an object back. The server must separate the data to the corresponding tables.

```
PUT /object/{guid} <--
 {
    lastname: "Doe", prename: "John", sex: "m",
    guid: "{guid}", owner: "123",  // object specific Attributes
    categories: [
         "green", "blue"
    }
}
```

What is a good pattern? Could Entity Framework (Database-first) do this? Would you go for a manual linq-sql based solution? Are there other suitable libraries for this task?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the database you're working with is storing information in a way that's easy to map directly to objects you are using directly in your business logic.

If you're trying to create a .net web microservice that will give you the ability to store and retrieve information from this legacy database, I would recommend using an ORM like EntityFramework to map the tables (either Database- first or [Code-First from Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx)).

I'd then recommend looking at using the [Repository Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) with your entities to maximize testability and isolate your data layer.